# Key_Down event doesn't trigger on Macs using ZeroBrane Turtle library

Tags: wxwidgets, zerobrane

I've been using ZeroBrane & its included Turtle library to teach (very) basic programming skills to young kids. This week is the 2nd time a kid has come with a Mac, and both times the char() function didn't work in their code. I tracked it back as far as I am capable, and the key variable (which is used in the char function) is never set in this line of code:

frame:Connect(wx.wxEVT_KEY_DOWN, function (event) key = event:GetKeyCode() end)

The current student is running Yosemite (I don't know if the previous student was using the same version or a different OS X version).

Any suggestions on where to look to resolve?

Comment: what version of the library is used?

Comment: The version of the Turtle library? I don't see a version number listed. It was downloaded from the ZeroBrane site and installed last week and I don't see any updates since then, so I believe it's the most current version.

Comment: no I'm asking about wx version. Because it is possible that wx was compiled for the older version of OSX...

Comment: @Igor, it's compiled using the wxwidgets master branch as of commit `7d9d5934`. I did confirm that the `EVT_KEY_DOWN` event doesn't fire when connected to wxFrame, but put a partial workaround in place for now.